# Gradle sync fails after upgrading Android Studio to 2.3 Beta 1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

My Gradle sync fails with the following error message in the log:

```
Gradle sync failed: com.android.builder.model.AndroidProject.getProjectType()I
```

and this error pop up (The yellowish box that pops up at top of the gradle file in android studio):

```
Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly.
```

What does this mean, and any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: What happens when you run `./gradlew build` from the command line in your project folder?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I just restarted Android studio and gradle synced. Maybe it was a cache problem?

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed it!